# virtualbox internet not working win7(host) RHEL 6.8(2 VMs)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, rhel

I know this question has been asked numerous times and have been answered differently all the times and that is why I am unable to get it working for myself.

I have a Windows 7 running Oracle virtualbox. I am trying to set up 2 * RHEL6.8 VMs(1 with X Windows, 1 on non-gui based console) both having internet connection on them and able to ping each other. I tried using NAT and bridged network settings for VMs and couldn't get it working. My hose Win 7 machine is running on Wi-Fi.

Has anybody tried above setup? Can someone point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First bring down any one network adapter(ifdown eth0) and try to connect internet. Do it for second one also by shutting first adapter. You should able to connect internet using both adapter.

Track which adapter having issue in connecting internet. And solve the issue of that adapter. If only one adapter is working, then make sure that adapter have entry in route table to access internet. (Remove another adapter entry from route table).